# Where to keep utility functions in angular2 that are available in templates

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a few simple "pure" utility functions in my app which i want to keep in one place. The problem is, i can import them in my components by using:

```
import { utilities } from '../shared/utilities'
```

However these utility function/methods are not available in my template files (because they are bound to the component class only). I have to create an alias of these functions in my component in order to use them. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the utilities in the template if you inject it in your controller.
Something like this :

```
import { Utilities } from './shared/utils';

@Component({
    ....
    ....
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    constructor(public util: Utilities) { }
}
```

In your template you should be able to use `util.your_function`

Update:

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    constructor(public util: Utilities) { }

    get staticMethod1() { return Utilities.staticMethod1(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - It works now, however the methods which are declared `static` in my class are still not accessible in the template file. Any work around for them?

Comment: For the utility methods that are static, should you prefer to make them as Pipes.

Comment: Also you could use getters in your component to access the static methods. I've updated the answer.

Comment: With this approach, how would the utils be included into some module that will be lazy loaded?

Comment: Unless the functions all relate, making them into a class is an example of low cohesion.  Framework programming is antithetical to structured design.