# Angular - how to use a utility function from a template

Tags: angular

I have a Helper class which defines a static method 'keyDown' which takes the key that was pressed.

I use it in several components, where it was just defined as a method on the component class, called from the template, like this:

```
     <input type="number"
       ...
       (keydown)="keyDown($event)"
       pattern="^(\d?[0-9]|[1-9]0)$"
       required/>
```

But duplicating that code is not good, so I put it into a static class, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205814/where-to-keep-utility-functions-in-angular2-that-are-available-in-templates/43205975)

```
export abstract class Helper {
  public static keyDown($event: any) {...}
}
```

Component:

```
import { Helper } from '../../../utils/helper';

  constructor(
    private helper: Helper,
  ) { }

  get keyDown(v) { return Helper.keyDown(v); }
```

This does not work because you cannot pass values to getters.

So how can I have a shared utility function that is called from the template of different components?

**UPDATE - I tried this.**

Credit to @CharlesBarnes for his comment. This almost worked!

I made 3 subtle but important changes:

1. The class method is no longer static:

```js
    export abstract class Helper {
      public keyDown($event: any) {...}
    }
```

2. The injected helper is no longer private, but **public**. This means the template can now **see** all methods in the helper class, so it can call them directly:

```js
    import { Helper } from '../../../utils/helper';
    
      constructor(
        public helper: Helper,
      ) { }
```

3. Finally I changed the template to prefix the method call with the name of the injected class (lower case 'helper'):

```js
     <input type="number"
       ...
       (keydown)="helper.keyDown($event)"
       pattern="^(\d?[0-9]|[1-9]0)$"
       required/>
```

But it throws a

```
NullInjectioNError, no provider for 'Helper'
```

:(

This kind-of implies to turn the Helper class into a service, and make it injectable.

...but that seems overkill to provide some general-purpose helper utilities.

Comment: Would changing a getter into a regular method `getKeyDown(v)` solve the problem?

Comment: @user776686 Only partly...the template would have to call that, so every component would need that regular method added, which would then call the static method on the class, passing the value it got passed from the template. I was hoping to avoid this double hop.

Comment: You could create your own directive to wrap/replace `keyDown`

Comment: You will avoid the double hop by changing the Helper class' keyDown method to a nonstatic member.  Then in the template you will just call helper.keyDown()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very good beginning. You are close to the solution.

So far you have only declared an `abstract` class, which now needs to be implemented by another class which can be instantiated.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHelper implements Helper {
  keyDown(e: KeyboardEvent){
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Now the class can be provided. I would do that on a component level:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Helper } from './helper';
import { MyHelper } from './my-helper';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: Helper, useClass: MyHelper }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
    public helper: Helper,
  ) { }
}
```

HTML remains as is.

```
(keydown)="helper.keyDown($event)"
```

And I would say this is actually a good pattern, because another component might use a different implementation of the keydown handler. This keeps the code uncoupled while strongly-typed through an abstract class.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. Angular still complains that there is no injector for 'helper'. So you need to add @Injectable. You've added a provider at the component level. That means a LOT of code to just inject a simple helper function. I may as well implement it as a service and provide it at the module level, rather than every component (although I agree with you that different implementations of the handler would be better provided at the component level). Less code, less work. So the short answer to my question is basically "you can't, you need to make a service" ;)

Comment: MyHelper does not call Helper.onKeyDown() => it just logs to console. But I should point out that if you add ```return Helper.onKeyDown(e) // call the base method``` then Angular complains "Helper.onKeyDown is not a function" WHEN myHelper is provided at the module level. So you have to provide it at the component level, as you've suggested